# jQuery remove event handler which is specified in the View

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

My understanding is that when using the `unbind` and `off` jQuery methods, I should be able to remove an event handler from an element as follows

The textbox created in the view, with an `onkeypress` event handler applied

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(Function(m) m.sometext, New With {.onkeypress = "eventhandler();", .id = "theID"}
```

The JavaScript which is trying to remove the event

```
function eventhandler()
{
    alert("should only hit once");

    // this doesnt unbind the event
    $("#theID").unbind("onkeypress");
    // Nor does
    $("#theID").off();
    //???
}
```

My thinking could be that the `unbind` only works with `bind` and the `off` only works when `on` is used. I say this as the jQuery API website states

> The .off() method removes event handlers that were attached with .on()

If this is the case, can I not apply the handler in the view at all?

I'd like to add I want to do this in the view and I want to apply a unique ID which is from the `ViewModel`

Any help would be helpful

Thanks

Comment: You can try `$('#theID').removeAttr('onkeypress');` or `$('#theID'')[0].onkeypress = null;`

Comment: Yes prefect. The lesson here is don't think too hard. The simpler answers tend to be the best. If you write it as an answer, I will mark it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use either `removeAttr()`

```
$('#theID').removeAttr('onkeypress');
```

*or* set the event handler to `null`

```
$('#theID'')[0].onkeypress = null;
```